# как посчитать сумму элементов Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Есть массив, из него я беру четные элементы стоящие на нечетных местах, записываю в новый массив, а дальше нужно посчитать сумму элементов в новом массиве и вывести в текстовое поле, но где-то видимо не правильное приведение типов

```
fun masCount(view: View) {
        val countString = textView.text.toString(); // получаем значение из поля


        val arrayItems = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        val evenItems = emptyArray<Int>();
        for ((index, value) in arrayItems.withIndex()) {
            if ((value % 2) == 0) {
                if((index)!=0){
                    evenItems[index+0] = index;
                }
            }
        }

        textView.text = evenItems.sum(); // ругается вот на эту строчку

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы берете четные элементы, стоящие на всех местах, кроме первого. Вообще, можно сразу идти по индексами через один.

Comment: Полностью код активити и xml в студию. И большой совет на будущее - не задавайте OnClick в разметке.

Comment: вы задаёте пустой массив `val evenItems = emptyArray<Int>();`, и тут же в цикле обращаетесь к индексу `evenItems[index+0] = index;`, зачем? `;` в котлине можно не ставить в конце выражения

Comment: мне нужно взять первый массив, и из него вытащить сумму всех четных чисел, стоящих на нечетных местах

Comment: @АнтонКравцов у Вас второй массив пуст. Вы пытаетесь изменять, скажем, первый элемент пустого массива. Вместо того, чтобы добавить первый элемент.

Comment: а как тогда добавить элемент? метод add не срабатывает, пишет unresolved reference: add

Comment: Здравствуй, пожалуйста, скин полный код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
evenItems.sum() //возвращает Int
textView.text = ... //принимает String
```

Так что да, проблема в типах.

Решение очевидно:

```
textView.text = (evenItems.sum() ?: 0).toString()
```

Кроме того, у Вас неправильная работа с массивом, нужно так:

```
    val arrayItems = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val evenItems = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for(i in arrayItems.indicies){
        if(i%2 == 1 && arrayItems[i]%2 == 0) //четные элементы, стоящие на нечетных местах
            eventItems.add(arrayItems[i])
    }
```

Comment: тогда крашится приложение

Comment: @АнтонКравцов подправил ответ, проверяйте

Comment: тогда вылетает просто из приложения

Comment: @АнтонКравцов Научитесь читать логи, чтобы понимать причину.

Comment: @АнтонКравцов а с чем именно вылетает? из-за текущего варианта ответа точно вылетать не может.

Comment: добавил скриншот с логом ошибки

Comment: @АнтонКравцов обновил ответ с поправкой на ошибку (если, конечно, правильно понял ее причины)

Comment: тогда ругается на метод add, пишет unresolved reference: add

Comment: @АнтонКравцов вроде исправил) Студии под рукой нет, код по памяти пишу)

Comment: получилось!
а то значит метод indices?

Comment: @АнтонКравцов возвращает интервал индексов массива или списка. То есть если в массиве 10 элементов, то indicies вернет 0..9 (все числа от 0 до 9 включительно). Эквивалент `indicies`: `for(i in 0 until array.size){...}` Не забудьте отметить ответ правильным))

Comment: так проще `val evenItems = arrayItems.filterIndexed { index, x -> x % 2 == 0 && index != 0 }`

Comment: @IR42 думаю, человеку, не привыкшему к kotlin, это будет чуть сложнее понять. С циклами обычно все знакомы. Да и внутри он, по сути, сделает то, что я написал)

Comment: Думаю если человек решил писать на котлине, то ему надо привыкать к котлину. А значит надо учиться использовать котлиновские конструкции.